# How to plot a function, that is not properly defined in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, evaluation

After rather long and relatively complicated calcuations, I finally got to a point where all my $x(t)$ functions are

```
equationSolution = {0.015922 + (0.0000570403 - 
     0.000813858 I) C2 E^((-11.2868 - 344.474 I) t) + (0.0000570403 + 
     0.000813858 I) C1 E^((-11.2868 + 344.474 I) t) - (0.00277545 - 
     0.0208373 I) C6 E^((-5.40686 - 40.5931 I) t) - (0.00277545 + 
     0.0208373 I) C5 E^((-5.40686 + 40.5931 I) t) + (1.79914*10^-18 - 
     0.00355291 I) C4 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 - 
      162.498 I) t) + (1.79914*10^-18 + 
     0.00355291 I) C3 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 + 162.498 I) t), 
 0.015922 - (0.0000644748 - 
     0.00196777 I) C2 E^((-11.2868 - 344.474 I) t) - (0.0000644748 + 
     0.00196777 I) C1 E^((-11.2868 + 344.474 I) t) - (0.0016191 - 
     0.00862548 I) C6 E^((-5.40686 - 40.5931 I) t) - (0.0016191 + 
     0.00862548 I) C5 E^((-5.40686 + 
      40.5931 I) t) - (8.57858*10^-19 - 
     0.00355291 I) C4 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 - 
      162.498 I) t) - (8.57858*10^-19 + 
     0.00355291 I) C3 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 + 162.498 I) t), 
 0.015922 - (0.0000644748 - 
     0.00196777 I) C2 E^((-11.2868 - 344.474 I) t) - (0.0000644748 + 
     0.00196777 I) C1 E^((-11.2868 + 344.474 I) t) - (0.0016191 - 
     0.00862548 I) C6 E^((-5.40686 - 40.5931 I) t) - (0.0016191 + 
     0.00862548 I) C5 E^((-5.40686 + 
      40.5931 I) t) + (1.00256*10^-18 - 
     0.00355291 I) C4 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 - 
      162.498 I) t) + (1.00256*10^-18 + 
     0.00355291 I) C3 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 + 162.498 I) t), 
 0.015922 - (0.280997 + 
     0.010463 I) C2 E^((-11.2868 - 344.474 I) t) - (0.280997 - 
     0.010463 I) C1 E^((-11.2868 + 344.474 I) t) + (0.860855 + 
     0. I) C6 E^((-5.40686 - 40.5931 I) t) + (0.860855 + 
     0. I) C5 E^((-5.40686 + 40.5931 I) t) - (0.577339 + 
     1.69348*10^-16 I) C4 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 - 
      162.498 I) t) - (0.577339 - 
     1.69348*10^-16 I) C3 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 + 162.498 I) t), 
 0.015922 + (0.678573 + 
     0. I) C2 E^((-11.2868 - 344.474 I) t) + (0.678573 + 
     0. I) C1 E^((-11.2868 + 344.474 I) t) + (0.358889 + 
     0.0190875 I) C6 E^((-5.40686 - 40.5931 I) t) + (0.358889 - 
     0.0190875 I) C5 E^((-5.40686 + 40.5931 I) t) + (0.577339 + 
     0. I) C4 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 - 162.498 I) t) + (0.577339 + 
     0. I) C3 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 + 162.498 I) t), 
 0.015922 + (0.678573 + 
     8.32667*10^-17 I) C2 E^((-11.2868 - 344.474 I) t) + (0.678573 - 
     8.32667*10^-17 I) C1 E^((-11.2868 + 344.474 I) t) + (0.358889 + 
     0.0190875 I) C6 E^((-5.40686 - 40.5931 I) t) + (0.358889 - 
     0.0190875 I) C5 E^((-5.40686 + 40.5931 I) t) - (0.577339 + 
     2.27914*10^-16 I) C4 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 - 
      162.498 I) t) - (0.577339 - 
     2.27914*10^-16 I) C3 E^((-1.42109*10^-14 + 162.498 I) t)}
```

Where there are two problems. I can't replace constants C1->C6 with those values

```
constants = {0.0164507 - 2.02961 I, 0.0164507 + 2.02961 I, 
 2.20498*10^-16 - 1.71741*10^-16 I, 
 2.50228*10^-16 - 1.3643*10^-16 I, -0.0285463 - 
  0.465175 I, -0.0285463 + 0.465175 I}
```

And I can't plot the functions using

```
Plot[equationSolution[[1]], {t, 0, 5}]
```

Anybody has an idea what to do?

I know that normally I should post a working example, but the code is quite long - approximately 100 lines.

Comment: Why can't you replace the constants? + I would strongly recommend naming the constants with lower case letters ...

Comment: @Bichoy doing `equationSolution=equationSolution/.constants` does not replace the C1 by it's value in the table constants. No idea why! The error says **{0.0164507 -2.02961 I,0.0164507 +2.02961 \
I,2.20498*10^-16-1.71741*10^-16 I,2.50228*10^-16-1.3643*10^-16 \
I,-0.0285463-0.465175 I,-0.0285463+0.465175 I} is neither a list of \
replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used \
for replacing. **

Comment: @skrat `equationSolution=equationSolution/.Thread[{C1,C2,...}->constants]` or on the rhs of `/.` you need to put a list of rules of the form `{C1->...,C2->...,...}`

Comment: @skrat unlikely comment above is the right way to do it ...

Comment: @unlikely: yep, this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Symbol` and `MapIndexed` to create a list of `Rule`s for use in `ReplaceAll` on `equationSolution`.

```
eqs = equationSolution /. MapIndexed[Symbol["C" <> ToString@First@#2] -> #1 &, constants];
```

Then you can use `ReIm` in `Plot` to separate the real and imaginary parts of each equation.  `PlotStyle` is used to give the same colour to each equations real and imaginary part while giving the imaginary part a `Dashed` line. `LineLegend` is used as a custom legend.

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm /@ eqs], {t, 0, .3},
 PlotRange -> Full,
 AxesLabel -> {t, None},
 PlotStyle -> (Sequence @@ {Directive[Thin, ColorData[1][#]], 
       Directive[Dashed, ColorData[1][#]]} & /@ Range[Length@eqs]),
 PlotLegends -> Column@{
    LineLegend@*Sequence @@ 
     Transpose[{ColorData[1][#], "Eq. " <> ToString@#} & /@ 
       Range[Length@eqs]],
    LineLegend[{Thin, Dashed}, {"Real", "Imaginary"}]
    },
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

However, the imaginary parts of the equations are very small so it may be worth plotting these in their own chart or use some of the two y-axis plot methods found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=2%20axis%20plot).

Hope this helps.