# NDSolve and matrix formulation do not produce the same result. Why and which is more precise?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Let's assume a vector of variables $\vec a=(a_1(t),a_2(t),a_3(t))$ and let's assume a following DE$$C\ddot{\vec a}=B\dot{\vec a}+A\vec{a}+\vec F.$$
If $A$ and $C$ are both reversible, than the DE can be written as $$\ddot{\vec a}=C^{-1}B\dot{\vec a}+C^{-1}A(\vec a+A^{-1}\vec F)$$ now making a crucial step $${(\vec a+A^{-1}\vec F)}''=C^{-1}B{(\vec a+A^{-1}\vec F)}'+C^{-1}A(\vec a+A^{-1}\vec F)$$ where $'$ still denotes a time derivative - it's just a cleaner syntax.
By saying $(\vec a+A^{-1}\vec F)=\vec u$ we derived a very compact form of the second ordered DE system
$${\vec u }''=C^{-1}B{\vec u}'+C^{-1}A\vec u.$$
To reduce the order from second to first we define yet another vector $\vec v={\vec u}'$. Doing so, our system can be rewritten in the following form $${\binom{\vec u}{\vec v}}'=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &I \\ 
 C^{-1}A&C^{-1}B 
\end{pmatrix}\binom{\vec u}{\vec v}$$ which is in a $${\vec z}'=H\vec z$$ form and can be solved via eigensystems theories
$$\vec z (t)=\sum C_k\vec \lambda _ke^{\lambda_kt}$$ for eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ and eigenvectors $\vec \lambda_k$.

**PROBLEM**
The system can be "easily" solved via `NDSolve[]`. The equations are

```
    equations = {800000. φ1[t] - 800000. φ3[t] + 
     0.105 (16858.8 Derivative[1][φ1][t] + 
        16858.8 Derivative[1][φ2][t] + 
        229 (-176.58 + 10.08 φ1''[t] + 
           6.93 φ2''[t] - 3.15 φ3'' [t])) == 0, 
   1.2*10^6 φ2[t] - 400000. φ3[t] + 
     0.105 (16858.8 Derivative[1][φ1][t] + 
        16858.8 Derivative[1][φ2][t] + 
        229 (-117.72 + 6.93 φ1''[t] + 
           6.3 φ2''[t] - 3.15 φ3''[t])) == 0, 
   1415.29 - 800000. φ1[t] - 400000. φ2[t] + 
     2.*10^6 φ3[t] - 75.7418 φ1''[t] - 
     75.7418 φ2''[t] + 60.5934 φ3''[t] == 0};
```

and using "brutal" `NDSolve[]`

```
n = 4;

variables = 
  Table[ToExpression["φ" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, n}];


For[i = 1, i <= n - 1, i++, 
  AppendTo[equations, variables[[i]][t] == 0 /. t -> 0]];

For[i = 1, i <= n - 1, i++, 
  AppendTo[equations, D[variables[[i]][t], t] == 0 /. t -> 0]];

solution = 
  Quiet[NDSolve[Rationalize[equations], 
    Table[variables[[i]][t], {i, 1, n - 1, 1}], {t, 0, 5}]];

koti = Table[solution[[1, i, 2]], {i, 1, n - 1, 1}];

Plot[koti, {t, 0, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t [s]", "φ [rad]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Courier New", FontSize -> 10}]
```

produces

[image]

HOWEVER using all the theory written above and the code below produces something... well something that does not look the same. Make sure you clear the "equations" because at this point boundary conditions were added.

```
        matrixSecondD = 
  Normal@CoefficientArrays[
     equations, {φ1''[t], φ2''[t], φ3''[
       t]}][[2]];

matrixFirstD = -Normal@
    CoefficientArrays[
      Normal@CoefficientArrays[
         equations, {φ1''[t], φ2''[
           t], φ3''[t]}][[1]], {φ1'[
        t], φ2'[t], φ3'[t]}][[2]];

matrixZeroD = -Normal@
    CoefficientArrays[
      Normal@CoefficientArrays[
         Normal@
          CoefficientArrays[
            equations, {φ1''[t], φ2''[
              t], φ3''[t]}][[1]], {φ1'[
           t], φ2'[t], φ3'[t]}][[
        1]], {φ1[t], φ2[t], φ3[t]}][[2]];

matrixNonhomogeneousPart = -Normal@
    CoefficientArrays[
      Normal@CoefficientArrays[
         Normal@CoefficientArrays[
            equations, {φ1''[t], φ2''[
              t], φ3''[t]}][[1]], {φ1'[
           t], φ2'[t], φ3'[t]}][[
        1]], {φ1[t], φ2[t], φ3[t]}][[1]];

matrixSecondD.{φ1''[t], φ2''[t], φ3''[
     t]} == matrixFirstD.{φ1'[t], φ2'[
      t], φ3'[t]} + 
   matrixZeroD.{φ1[t], φ2[t], φ3[t]} + 
   matrixNonhomogeneousPart;

id = IdentityMatrix[3];

zeroes = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];

matrix = ArrayFlatten[{{zeroes, 
     id}, {Inverse[matrixSecondD].matrixZeroD, 
     Inverse[matrixSecondD].matrixFirstD}}];

eigenVal = Eigensystem[matrix][[1]];

eigenVec = Eigensystem[matrix][[2]];

constants = Table[ToExpression["C" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 2 (n - 1)}];

freeMatrix = Inverse[matrixZeroD].matrixNonhomogeneousPart;

equationSolution = 
  Sum[Table[
     constants[[i]]*Exp[eigenVal[[i]]*t] eigenVec[[i]] - 
      If[i <= (n - 1), freeMatrix[[i]], 0], {i, 1, Length[eigenVal], 
      1}][[j]], {j, 1, 2 (n - 1)}];

equationsForConst = 
  Table[equationSolution[[i]] == 0 /. t -> 0, {i, 1, 
    Length[eigenVal]}];

system = Solve[equationsForConst, constants];

constants = constants /. Flatten[system];

equationSolution = 
  equationSolution /. 
   Thread[Table[
      ToExpression["C" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 2 (n - 1)}] -> 
     constants];

koti = Drop[equationSolution, -(n - 1)];

Plot[Evaluate[ReIm /@ koti], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 AxesLabel -> {t, None}, 
 PlotStyle -> (Sequence @@ {Directive[Thin, ColorData[1][#]], 
       Directive[Dashed, ColorData[1][#]]} & /@ Range[Length@koti]), 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Column@{LineLegend@*Sequence @@ 
     Transpose[{ColorData[1][#], "Eq. " <> ToString@#} & /@ 
       Range[Length@koti]], 
    LineLegend[{Thin, Dashed}, {"Real", "Imaginary"}]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Why are solutions to the DE system not the same in both cases? And which one is the correct one?
NOTE that this is the first time I am working with matrices in mathematica, so there is probably a really stupid mistake somewhere.

ps: that last part (plotting the real and imaginary party) is a copy paste code from *Edmund* in [THIS](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111210/how-to-plot-a-function-that-is-not-properly-defined-in-mathematica/111219#111219) answer.

Comment: Check you power cable for RF coupling :)

Comment: @Dr.belisarius: no comment :D made my day.

Comment: Can you uses  a simpler example for which you know the solution first? It's a bit early here, but how do you know that `a = (a+A^(-1) F)` Am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to correct your first code block so that it works properly;  you seem to be taking derivatives using expressions like `(φ1^′′)[t]`, which is definitely not right.

Comment: @user21: That's my defintion. Why do I use it? Because I couldn't find an easier way to convert my starting system into a final homogeneous system of first order DE - which I can solve via the eigensystem. Why `u = (a+A^(-1) F)` and not something else? Because with this definition I don't change the equation. Note that `A^(-1) F` is a constant vector.
@MichaelSeifert: That's a notation this forum uses. If you copy paste the code in Mathematica, it should give you the derivatives.

Comment: If you make such a definition don't you have to replace all a with the definition? It's not done in the constant term. Now, I understand for eigenvalues the constant term is not relevant but for a time integration it is.

Comment: It definitely doesn't return the correct thing on my computer when I copy and paste it into Mathematica.  `FullForm[(φ1^′′)[t]]` gives `Power[\[CurlyPhi]1, \[Prime]\[Prime]][t]`;  `FullForm[φ1''[t]]` gives `Derivative[2][\[CurlyPhi]1][t]`.

Comment: It might be good if explain a bit more about the transformation you do. Forget the last part of my previous message I was thinking you use NDSolve for time integration but you don't. Do you have a PDE for this, then you could use `NDEigensystem`

Comment: Also:  I don't think you define `eigenVec` and `eigenVal` in your last code block.  I assume that they're the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of `matrix`, but you might want to throw those in as well.

Comment: Note that in your second method, `D[koti, t] /. t -> 0` does not return `{0,0,0}` (or anything close to "machine zero"), as it seems like it should given your initial conditions.  I suspect the problem is in the application of your initial conditions.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ok, I don't know how to comment those derivatives. I have no idea why and how this happens but I have changed the code in the OP where I got rid of this strange syntax.

Comment: To all: I thought I had published a working example (code) I guess I was wrong. I edited my OP, so the code above should work now - checked it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert where did you find `D[koti, t] /. t -> 0` ? Where is that?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius [this](http://www.machinadynamica.com/machina31.htm) will fix the problem (see bottom of page).

Comment: @Jens I don't know why I never realize of all those brilliant business opportunities out there until someone else shows them to me :(

Comment: @skrat:  I got your code working on my own last night (before you revised it) and reproduced your results.  I then tried evaluating the derivative of your solution at $t = 0$, and noted that it did not equal 0.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.  I'll look at your new code if I have some time later this afternoon.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Please do, If you find extra free time.

Comment: Could you somehow calculate the residuals of your equations from both methods and compare them?

Comment: @MathX Honestly, that's way over my level of knowledge. I have absolutely no idea what residuals are and what information do they give nor do i have an idea on how to calculate them.

Comment: See, in general, you are solving a set of equations: F(x(t),y(t),x'(t),y'(t),..)=0. Your solution should satisfy these equations. So a perfect solution, if put back in the equations, should result in very small values i.e. residuals. i am not exactly sure how to do this for your problem, but If you have two different solutions, you can plug them back in and see that for example the solution you got at each point is not equal to zero but a very small number at each point of your domain. Comparing the sum (integral) of the residuals of two different solutions could be a good test.

Comment: I haven't done this in Mathematica to be able to give you a code, and hence, I am commenting so that maybe it could be helpful.

Comment: Maybe if you interpolate your matrix solution linearly (order 1) you could then plug the resulting  `InterpolatingFunctions` in your system of equations to see how good they perform.

Comment: Check http://wolfram.com/xid/0fz357o5dwtdew-btca6z  
In[109] gives an example of what I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So Mathematica can, in fact, solve your equations exactly using `DSolve` instead of `NDSolve`:

```
solution = DSolve[equations, variables, t];
koti = {\[CurlyPhi]1[t], \[CurlyPhi]2[t], \[CurlyPhi]3[t]} /. solution;
Plot[Evaluate[Re /@ koti], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Full, 
           AxesLabel -> {t, None}, PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Note that I removed the `Rationalize` from `equations` before feeding it into `DSolve`.  If you don't, Mathematica will try to work with exact roots of sixth-order polynomials, and that way lies madness.

What I noticed in this graph is that the green graph is not as smooth as one would expect.  This non-smoothness persists even if you increase the number of plot points (note the high value of `PlotPoints` in the above code) and if you zoom in on the graph:

[image]

This looks like a large oscillation with a very small oscillation superposed on it. Notably, in your second method, `eigenVal` works out to be

```
(* {-11.2869 + 344.474 I, -11.2869 - 344.474 I, -9.99201*10^-15 + 162.498 I, 
    -9.99201*10^-15 - 162.498 I, -5.40686 + 40.5931 I, -5.40686 - 40.5931 I} *)
```

and $2\pi/344.474 \approx 0.018$, which matches up nicely with the period of the small oscillations you can see on the graph above.

What I suspect is happening here is that your system has a high-frequency mode whose corresponding amplitude $C_k$ is low in the "true" solution.  However, something is going wrong with your application of boundary conditions;  resulting in this high-frequency oscillation being assigned a much higher amplitude $C_k$, making it noticeable.

**In conclusion:**  the results of `NDSolve` and `DSolve` are generally consistent with each other.  Moreover, a close examination of those two results has convinced me that there is an error in your home-brew method (in particular, the application of the initial conditions) that results in the weird-looking solution that is generated.

As an aside: `DSolve` is probably using a version of your algorithm to solve the equation exactly.  But when I have a choice between using pre-tested algorithms to accomplish a task versus writing my own, I'll use the pre-tested algorithms every time.

Comment: My dear friend, I can't thank you enough! That's a very clear a nice explanation AND a super simple way to solve my system instead of what I was doing. Thank you big time: I had no idea Rationalize makes that much mess. Also thanks for making it clear what went wrong in my second method.

Comment: However, after taking a closer look, does this explain the high difference in the stationary state? You can see for your self: My first plot (blue line) converges to some value below 0.010, yet the graph I got with the matrix method converges to a value above 0.015. That is... a lot relatively to the maximum value.

Comment: @skrat. In case you missed the edit to my answer I got the matrix method to work (a1 converges to 0.00884556)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have made some error, the eigensystem approach is shown to work:

First, You may find it useful to know that `NDSolve` can work directly with vector equations: (This is also validating the first part of your manipulation)

```
a={{8, 0, -8}, {0, 12, -4}, {-8, -4, 20}} 10^5
b={{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} 1770.17
c={{-32, -22, 10}, {-22, -20, 10}, {10, 10, -8}} 7.57418
f={-3, -2, 1} 1415.29
ia = Inverse[a];
ic = Inverse[c];
sol = First@NDSolve[ {
          u''[t] == (ic.a).u[t] + (ic.b).u'[t] ,
            u[0] == ia.f,
           u'[0] == {0, 0, 0}
                               }, u[t], {t, 0, 5}]
aa[t_, i_] := (u[t] /. sol)[[i]] - (ia.f)[[i]]
Plot[aa[t, 1], {t, 0, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

your first order form gives the same result:

```
h = {{ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}], IdentityMatrix[3]}, {ic.a, ic.b}};
sol = First@NDSolve[{
    {u'[t], v'[t]} == { 
      h[[1, 1]].u[t] + h[[1, 2]].v[t],
      h[[2, 1]].u[t] + h[[2, 2]].v[t]},
    {u[0], v[0]} == {ia.f, {0, 0, 0}}}, {u[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

I think this capability is fairly new.. (this is v10.1). unfortunately it doesn't appear to generalize to higher order tensor  this throws an error:

```
 NDSolve[{z'[t] == h.z[t], z[0] == {ia.f, {0, 0, 0}}}, z[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

we can however pose this as a 6-vector, using  a 6x6 form of h:

```
h66 = {
   Join[h[[1, 1, 1]], h[[1, 2, 1]]],
   Join[h[[1, 1, 2]], h[[1, 2, 2]]],
   Join[h[[1, 1, 3]], h[[1, 2, 3]]],
   Join[h[[2, 1, 1]], h[[2, 2, 1]]],
   Join[h[[2, 1, 2]], h[[2, 2, 2]]],
   Join[h[[2, 1, 3]], h[[2, 2, 3]]]};
(* surely some incantation of Flatten[h,levelspec] does the same..*)
sol = First@
  NDSolve[{z'[t] == h66.z[t], z[0] == Flatten[{ia.f, {0, 0, 0}}]}, 
   z[t], {t, 0, 5}]
aa[t_, i_] := (z[t] /. sol)[[i]] - (ia.f)[[i]]
Plot[aa[t, 1], {t, 0, 1.5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> same plot

Now we can apply your eigensystem solution:

```
{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[h66];
csol = First@
   Solve[ Sum[ cc[k] evec[[k]] , {k, 6}] == 
     Flatten[{ia.f, {0, 0, 0}}] , Array[cc, 6]];
eigsol = Sum[ (cc[k] /. csol) evec[[k]] Exp[eval[[k]] t], {k, 6}];
Plot[Table[Re[eigsol[[k]]] - (ia.f)[[k]], {k, 3}], {t, 0, 2}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

> Exact same plot ( no noise ! )

[image]

limit value `Chop[eigsol[[1]] - (ia.f)[[1]] /. t -> Infinity]`

> 0.00884556

which is `First@(-Inverse[a].f)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, maybe just one comment: Noise is not the problem - right the opposite: due to the physical laws of the system I would expect some superposition but absolutely not as much as I get with my matrix method described in the OP.

Comment: i guess noise is not the right word. Your matrix solution shows a high frequency component not present in the direct solution.  I'm guessing some error - compare your `matrix` with my `h66` i think they should be the same although I didn't check that part of your code.

Comment: This works nicely, but never came across that syntax `koti[t_, i_] := (u[t] /. 
     sol)[[i]] - (Inverse[matrixZeroD].matrixNonhomogeneousPart)[[i]]` which works nicely for plotting but doesn't work at all if I want to use it in equation `yKoordinateA = -l Sum[koti[t, i], {i, 1, n/2, 1}];` and plot `yKoordinateA` or get some numerical values.